# UIButton that increments an array from Core Data, done from another class

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, core-data, uibutton

I have a button that whenever it is pressed is supposed to increment by one, which as a result will display a new string into a textfield. I have a Core Data manager class that contains a method which is supposed to retrieve my arrays, however whenever I press the button the app crashes. I'm left with an error stating ...

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UsefulCodes rangeOfCharacterFromSet:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6000000a3f60'"
```

"UsefulCodes" is the name of my Core Data entity, and "codeName" and "codeDescription" are the attributes fro my presetList and codeDescArray respectively. I think its not working because I'm trying to put a Core Data object into a textfield, but all the objects in the arrays are strings, how would I get it to pass successfully into the textfield? I'll post relevant code below.

From CoreDataManager -

```
@implementation CoreDataManager

+(CoreDataManager*)sharedInstance {
    static CoreDataManager *sharedObject;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedObject = [[CoreDataManager alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedObject;
}


-(void)storeListFirstTime {

    //http://morsecode.scphillips.com/morse.html
    NSArray* presetList = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"AS",
                                                   @"BCNU",
                                                   @"CL",
                                                   @"CT",
                                                   @"CUL",
                                                   @"K",
                                                   @"QSL",
                                                   @"QSL?",
                                                   @"QRX?",
                                                   @"QRV",
                                                   @"QRV?",
                                                   @"QTH",
                                                   @"QTH?",
                                                   @"R",
                                                   @"SN",
                                                   @"SOS",
                                                   @"73",
                                                   @"88",
                                                   nil];


    NSArray* codeDescArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Wait",
                                                      @"Be seeing You",
                                                      @"Going off air",
                                                      @"Start Copying",
                                                      @"See you later",
                                                      @"Over",
                                                      @"I acknowledge receipt",
                                                      @"Do you acknowledge",
                                                      @"Should I wait",
                                                      @"Ready to copy",
                                                      @"Are you ready to copy?",
                                                      @"My location is ...",
                                                      @"What is your location?",
                                                      @"Roger",
                                                      @"Understood",
                                                      @"Distress message",
                                                      @"Best regards",
                                                      @"Love and kisses",
                                                      nil];

    //Saves the initial list of items
    for(int i = 0; i < presetList.count; i++) {
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context];
        UsefulCodes *codeObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"UsefulCodes"
                                                             inManagedObjectContext:context];
        codeObj.codeName = [presetList objectAtIndex:i];
        codeObj.codeDescription = [codeDescArray objectAtIndex:i];

        NSLog(@"CODEOBJ: %@", codeObj);
    }

    [self saveContext];
}

//THIS IS THE METHOD I AM CALLING FOR MY BUTTON METHOD
-(NSArray*)fetchAllRecords {

    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self context]; //this context is conected to persistant container
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"UsefulCodes"];
    NSArray *records = [context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

    if(error == nil && records.count > 0) {
        return [records copy];
    }
    else {
        //Handle error by returning new array
        return [NSArray new];
    }
}
```

The above code just sets the initial values I hard-coded into my arrays (I'm only interested in getting the values from presetList array to display in textfield) as well as accommodating any new codes and descriptions I've added to any arrays. Now here is the method in my "MainViewController" responsible for cycling through my array.

In header file I declare a property called num.

```
@property(nonatomic)int num;
```

This is the method in implementation file.

```
- (void)getQuickMorseCode {

    NSArray *array = [[CoreDataManager sharedInstance] fetchAllRecords];

    if(_num == 0 || _num > 0) {
        if(_num >= array.count){
            _num = 0;
        }
        //GETTING THE SPECIFIC INDEX OF THE ARRAY, THIS IS WHERE THE PROBLEM LIES
        self.morseTextfield.text = array[_num];
        [self convertInput:self.morseTextfield.text];
        [self buttonAppear];
        _num++;
    }
}
```

My goal is to display the strings that are in the presetList array in my CoreDataManager file, but I'm unable to get that to pass into my textfield. Any insight to my problem is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fetchAllRecords` method returns an array of `UsefulCodes` objects.  So each element of `array` is a `UsefulCodes` object.  You cannot therefore assign the element to the `text` property of a textfield.  That's the cause of your error.

You need instead to extract the relevant string from the `UsefulCodes` object.  From your other code, you store the `presetList` values in the `codename` attribute of the `UsefulCodes` objects:

```
codeObj.codeName = [presetList objectAtIndex:i];
```

So, reverse that process to obtain the relevant string from the `codename` attribute:

```
UsefulCodes *codeObj = (UsefulCodes *)array[_num];
NSString *presetListValue = codeObj.codeName;
self.morseTextfield.text = presetListValue;
```